# HTML positioning element without blank space

Tags: html, css

I have two elements (images)

imgA is 2000px high
imgB is 1000px high

I place them one after the other and then move imgB up (I use relative positioning) to overlap the imgA.

Thus, the window in the browser should be 2000px high.

However, it seems, that when placing imgA and then imgB, the browser allocates the place for both of them i.e. 3000px hig, and after I move imgB up to overlap imgA, I have a blank space =1000px left at the bottom of the page.

How can this blank space be prevented?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `position: absolute;`. Relative (iirc) reserves its space within the document flow, but absolute takes it out of the flow.

Comment: Thanks all. Kyle, how do I mark your answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Ignore this**

> This is because the images are block level elements. To stop the
>   browser from allocating space you can just add: `display:inline-block`
>   to the second image. This will bring the image out of block structure
>   and so the browser will not allocate it whitespace.

Also have a look at [Relatively Absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/), it is very handy for the sort of thing you are doing.

---

***EDITED***

As commented below, this does not work. Use instead the [Relatively Absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

[Here is a jsFiddle that shows the code needed to position an image over another](http://jsfiddle.net/RAkqC/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block` on your images, then use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative` to position imgB over imgA.

Don't forget to assign the parent element to anything other than `position: static` to make the positioning of your image relative to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

for further clarification you can see the examples of "css block" here

http://www.tutorialswire.com/css/css-display

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning is only a specific solution to your case. It may not work in some similar case (For example if you have other elements on top of those two images inside the general containing div).

I believe best solution would be using

```
margin-top: -1000px;
```

for the second image.